# Is there any syntactic sugar to using group by columns 1,2,3,...,n in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I know it isn't a "good way of doing things", but we use the following notations in many of our SQL queries :

```sql
SELECT dim_1,dim_2,...,dim_n,agg_function(metric_1),...agg_function(metric_k)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2,...,n
```

I was wondering if there is an even more succinct way of writing it, e.g. `GROUP BY 1-n` (Group by col_1 to col_n)

Comment: Tag your question only with the database you are using.  In any case, the answer is basically "no", regardless.

Comment: I'm using both databases

Comment: @Strawberry, This stuff is useful when doing POCs within ELT environments & test huge queries. Especially when it involves rewriting certain blocks several times, then doing it in this "abridged" way is quite helpful. Of course, once the query is validated then we translate the "ugly" numbers into their respective column names. But hey, let's all pretend syntactic sugar isn't a huge part of software dev. In fact, I'm confident this would be a great feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have table with dozen or more columns

Consider below template (note below `offset` is zero-based) for BigQuery - should be perfect for POC type of work you mentioned

```
select (
    select string_agg(kv)
    from unnest(split(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'))) kv with offset 
    where offset between 0 and N-1
  ) dims,
  agg_function(metric_1),...agg_function(metric_k)
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by 1
```

Below is dummy/simplistic example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 col1, '2' col2, 3 col3, 4 col4 union all 
  select 11, '2', 3, 41
)
select 
  (
    select string_agg(kv)
    from unnest(split(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'))) kv with offset 
    where offset in (1,2)
  ) dims,
  sum(col1) metric1, count(col1) metric2
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by 1
```

with output

[image]

Comment: How do you filter on dimensions if we aggregate them in a key, value format?

Comment: Thank you for your time @MikhailBerlyant, but while this is a clever way to put all dimensions together, it is not the same as what I asked. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: you asked for `... any syntactic sugar ...` - I gave you the option! obviously it is not just `group by 1-N` as it does not exists, while the workaround in my answer allows you to avoid mile long `SELECT dim_1,dim_2,...,dim_n,` and shorter but still lengthy `GROUP BY 1,2,...,n`! so i think my answer exactly answers your question :o)